# Magento 2: Is my cron running well?

Tags: magento2, cron, admin-panel, server-setup

As you can see in the image below, seems like my CRON is working well, but there is two index that was updated 6 days ago and isn't updating every day like the other.

How can I solve that?

[image]

Comment: If you didn't update these 2 data, you don't need to worry.

Answer (score 0):

The respective indices just need to be indexed when were populated in the CRON table in the database called **cron_schedule**, like the image below.

[image: cron table magento 2 database]

So, your indices related to the **Product Categories** and **Catalog Product Rules** gonna be reindexed when necessary to doesn't use an unnecessary resource.